# Contact Form Backend needed, Frontend given

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, contacts

I used to host a website at carrd.co with the pro plus plan. I chose the expensive plan because of the possibility to download the website and host it on an own server.

What I did not know, was that this did not include server-side code.

My problem is, that I have the front end code, but every PHP code I try fails to interact with this code. Since I can only develop with Java, I cannot get to a solution by myself.

The issue is that I do not know what the next step is to make this code work on my server so that it successfully sends me an email when this form is submitted by a user. I do not have any backend code and do not know where to start.

1) where can i put a PHP file to answer to this request? How do i have to name it?

2) how can i parse the arguments?

3) how do i have to format the answer from the php script to the ajax script?

Could you guys please help here? Thanks a lot!!!

(i might even be able to solve this with some good hints if you cannot be bothered to provide a full solution! I'm thankful for any advice!)

The frontend code:

Form:

```
<form id="form02" method="post">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="field"><input type="text"       name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"
                                                      maxlength="128"/></div>
                            <div class="field"><input type="email" name="email" id="email"
                                                      placeholder="Email" maxlength="128"/></div>
                            <div class="field"><input type="text" name="fname" id="-fname" placeholder="Fname"
                                                      maxlength="128"/></div>
                            <div class="field"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"
                                                         maxlength="16384"></textarea></div>
                            <div class="actions">
                                <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="form02"/>
</form>
```

Script:

```
function form(id, settings) {
var _this = this;
this.id = id;
this.mode = settings.mode;
this.method = settings.method;
this.success = settings.success;
this.preHandler = ('preHandler' in settings ? settings.preHandler : null);
this.failure = ('failure' in settings ? settings.failure : null);
this.optional = ('optional' in settings ? settings.optional : []);
this.$form = $('#' + this.id);
this.$form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    _this.submit(event);
});
this.$form.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.ctrlKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        _this.submit(event);
    }
});
var x = $('#' + this.id + ' input[name="' + settings.hid + '"]');
if (x) {
    x.disabled = true;
    x.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
this.$submit = $('#' + this.id + ' button[type="submit"]');
this.$submit.disabled = false;
};form.prototype.notify = function (type, message) {
if (message.match(/^(#[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+|[a-z0-9\-\.]+:[a-zA-Z0-  9\~\!\@\#$\%\&\-\_\+\=\;\,\.\?\/\:]+)$/)) location.href = message; else alert((type == 'failure' ? 'Error: ' : '') + message);
}; 

form.prototype.submit = function (event) {
var _this = this, result, handler, fd, k, x, $f, $ff;
event.preventDefault();
if (this.$submit.disabled) return;
result = true;
$ff = this.$form.elements;
for (k in $ff) {
    $f = $ff[k];
    if ($f.type != 'text' && $f.type != 'email' && $f.type != 'textarea' && $f.type != 'select-one') continue;
    if ($f.disabled) continue;
    if ($f.value === '' || $f.value === null) {
        if (this.optional.indexOf($f.name) !== -1) continue;
        result = false;
    } else {
        x = '';
        switch ($f.type) {
            case 'email':
                x = "^([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.\\+]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\\-     \\.]+)\\.([a-zA-Z]+)$";
                break;
            case 'select':
                x = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]$";
                break;
            default:
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                x = "^[^\\<\\>]+$";
                break;
        }
        result = result && $f.value.match(new RegExp(x));
    }
    if (!result) break;
}
if (!result) {
    this.notify('failure', 'Missing and/or invalid fields. Please try again.');
    return;
}
if (_this.method == 'get') {
    _this.$form.submit();
    return;
}
if (x = $(':focus')) x.blur();
this.$submit.disabled = true;
this.$submit.classList.add('waiting');
handler = function (values) {
    var x, k, data;
    data = new FormData(_this.$form);
    if (values) for (k in values) data.append(k, values[k]);
    x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('POST', ['', 'post', _this.mode].join('/'));
    x.send(data);
    x.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var result = false, message = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.', alert = true, o;
        if (x.readyState != 4) return;
        if (x.status == 200) {
            o = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
            if (o) {
                if ('result' in o) result = (o.result === true);
                if (('message' in o) && o.message) message = o.message;
                if ('alert' in o) alert = (o.alert === true);
            }
        }
        _this.$submit.classList.remove('waiting');
        if (result) {
            _this.$form.reset();
            if (alert) window.alert(message); else _this.notify('success', (_this.success ? _this.success : message));
        } else {
            if (alert) window.alert(message); else _this.notify('failure', (_this.failure ? _this.failure : message));
        }
        _this.$submit.disabled = false;
    };
};
if (_this.preHandler) (_this.preHandler)(_this, handler); else (handler)();
};
new form('form02', {mode: 'contact', method: 'post', hid: 'fname', success: '#contact-done',});
```

Comment: Java is a fine language for server side services and API's. There is alittle more to hosting a web app with a backend than just having the code though.....

Comment: An alternative would be to use a backend as a service like Firebase or use some other cloud service to host a simple php API

Comment: What is the specific issue here? I'm a little confused.

Comment: i updated the post and described the exact issue. The issue is that i do not know where to start when programming a backend that responds to this form.

Comment: I do have a server and everything it needs btw. The server side configuration is not a problem if i find any tutorial or anything.

Comment: I updated the question thanks to Graeme Chapman. Would be great if you guys could answer this questions :)

Answer (score 0):

An html form normally uses an `action` parameter to specify a url for the script to submit the form data to. However it looks like your javascript code is hard-coded to create an ajax post back to a url at `/post/contact`, which may explain why the examples you have tried do not work.

Yes, you do need a script of some kind on your server to process the response, but it doesn't have to be PHP - whatever your hosting provider supports, and whatever is capable of handling what you want to do with the data.

Comment: Wow, that explains a lot. Could you give me three more infos? 1) where can i put a PHP file to answer to this request? How do i have to name it? 2) how can i parse the arguments? 3) how do i have to format the answer from the php script to the ajax script?

Comment: btw: I only want to send myself an email. PHP should easily be sufficient for this..

Comment: Yes, php can definitely handle that. You're probably best off searching for a php ajax contact form tutorial, instead of trying to make something that works with undocumented third party javascript.

Comment: If you want to try from scratch, you should probably start with http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php to actually get the posted data.